# ocupload jQuery plugin not working when initialized inside event callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I'm using the ocupload plugin for jQuery to allow users of my app to upload an image to my server without a page refresh. Normally I don't have any difficulties with it but I'm attempting to initialize it within a click event callback, and it's simply not working. However if I try to initialize it after the click-event callback function completes by manually entering the initialization code into my js console it DOES work. Anyone know what I'm missing here?

```
    //Open dialog view for profile picture manipulation
jQuery('#admin_profile_picture_img').bind('click', function(){

    jQuery('#admin_profile_picture_img_dialog').dialog('open');

    //initialize one-click upload for profile picture
    window.myUpload = jQuery('#upload_new').upload({
        name: 'file',
        action: '',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        params: {},
        autoSubmit: true,
        onSubmit: function(){
            console.log('onSubmit()');
        },
        onComplete: function(){
            console.log('onComplete()');
        },
        onSelect: function(){
            console.log('onSelect()');
        }
    });

    console.log(window.myUpload);

});
```

**Edit**:

This is the HTML that goes with this question:

```
<div style="display:none" id="admin_profile_picture_img_dialog">
<img id="preview_profile_pic" src="http://vibecompass.s3.amazonaws.com/vc-images/profile-pics/c3d9262de038c507a9d86fae67145829.png" alt="profile picture" />
<a id="upload_new" href="#" style="background:#39f; font-size: 24px; color: white;">Click here to upload a photo</a>
```

**Edit 2**:

I have the same issue if I move the code into the 'open' event callback of the dialog.

```
    //initialize dialog for profile picture selection/crop
jQuery('#admin_profile_picture_img_dialog').dialog({
    draggable: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'modify profile picture',
    open: function(event, ui){
        setTimeout(function() {
            //initialize one-click upload for profile picture
            window.myUpload = jQuery('#upload_new').upload({
                name: 'file',
                action: '',
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                params: {},
                autoSubmit: true,
                onSubmit: function(){
                    console.log('onSubmit()');
                },
                onComplete: function(){
                    console.log('onComplete()');
                },
                onSelect: function(){
                    console.log('onSelect()');
                }
            });
        }, 500);
        console.log('should open');
    }
});
```

However once again, if I attempt to initiate it from my command line, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the code that's not working in a `setTimeout` call with a 1ms delay.  Ie,

```
//Open dialog view for profile picture manipulation
jQuery('#admin_profile_picture_img').bind('click', function(){

    jQuery('#admin_profile_picture_img_dialog').dialog('open');

    setTimeout(function() {
        //initialize one-click upload for profile picture
        window.myUpload = jQuery('#upload_new').upload({
            name: 'file',
            action: '',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            params: {},
            autoSubmit: true,
            onSubmit: function(){
                console.log('onSubmit()');
            },
            onComplete: function(){
                console.log('onComplete()');
            },
            onSelect: function(){
                console.log('onSelect()');
            }
        });
    }, 1);
    console.log(window.myUpload);
});
```

**Edit:** My hunch is that `$("#upload_new")` doesn't yet exist at this point in the code.  Is it created in the dialog's open event handler?  I'd try initializing the upload control in the dialog's open event handler.  Or, you could try the following method, which is a bit extreme, but should work:

```
//Open dialog view for profile picture manipulation
jQuery('#admin_profile_picture_img').bind('click', function(){

    jQuery('#admin_profile_picture_img_dialog').dialog('open');

    initializeUpload();

    function initializeUpload() {
        var $uploadNew = jQuery("#upload_new");
        if ($uploadNew.length == 0) {
            setTimeout(initializeUpload, 200);
        }
        else {
            window.myUpload = $uploadNew.upload({
                name: "file",
                ...
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that didn't work. It might be worth noting that this bind function is being called from a document on-ready function. The plugin works correctly if I initiate it from the command line after I open the jquery dialog it's contained in, then it does work

Comment: Is `$("#upload_new")` contained in the dialog?  If it hasn't been created yet, then you would be calling `.upload()` on an empty jQuery object.  Try initializing the plugin in the dialog's open event handler or maybe its focus event.  Or, try increasing the timeout's delay to something like 500ms.

Comment: I moved the code into the open event-handler but it still doesn't work unfortunately. I output $('#upload_new') with a console.log() it does return a reference to the dom object. Interestingly, if i console.log(window.myUpload) from the event handler it returns 'undefined' but if I run the same console.log(window.myUpload) from the terminal I do see the object.

Comment: Thanks @gilly3 I tried you're second 'more extreme' suggestion and that works. I tested it and the $uploadNew.length == 0 is FALSE every time btw